# Shell cannot find copied files in Docker Container

Tags: python, bash, docker, shell

I have a following Dockerfile for my python web project. It works perfectly however, entrypoint.sh script, cannot find some of the files, that suppose to be copied by Docker (internal files of the project).

My Dockerfile

```
FROM --platform=arm64 python:3.8.13-buster
LABEL maintainer=kirklimushin@gmail.com 

WORKDIR /project/dir/

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY ./src ./
COPY ./__init__.py ./
COPY ./unittests ./
COPY ./environment.env ./
COPY ./module_requirements.txt ./
COPY ./module_constraints.txt ./
COPY ./entrypoint.sh ./
COPY ./rest_controllers.py ./
COPY ./settings.py ./

# creating new virtual environment 
RUN python -m venv fn_env

# activating python virtual environment via shell
RUN . ./fn_env/bin/activate

# upgrading pip packet manager 

RUN pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel

# installing dependencies inside virtual environment

RUN pip install -r module_requirements.txt -c module_constraints.txt

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint.sh
```

My shell script `entrypoint.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting Entrypoint pipeline...."

echo "Activating Virtual Environment"

source ./project/dir/fn_env/bin/activate

pip list

echo "Running Unittests..."

pytest ./project/dir/unittests/ml/test_models.py
pytest ./project/dir/unittests/web/test_rest_controllers.py

echo "Starting ASGI Server..."

python ./project/dir/settings.py
```

As aforementioned Dockerfile seems to work well, however, when it runs `entrypoint.sh`, it throws following error:

```
/project/dir

Starting Entrypoint pipeline....

Activating Virtual Environment

Running Unittests...

./entrypoint.sh: line 9: ./project/dir/fn_env/bin/activate: No such file or directory


ERROR: file or directory not found: ./project/dir/unittests/ml/test_models.py


ERROR: file or directory not found: ./project/dir/unittests/web/test_rest_controllers.py
```

It cannot find files.

When I run `pwd` it shows, the current directory (aka. `/project/dir/`, which I specified inside my Dockerfile), so paths are supposed to be correct

Looks like Docker having trouble copying files?

Comment: `/project/dir/` is not  `./project/dir/`

Comment: ...since you specify `WORKDIR /project/dir`, you're already in that directory, and so you're looking for a path `/project/dir/project/dir/fn_env/...`.

Comment: (A Docker container is already an isolated environment separate from any other Python installation, so a common practice is to not use a virtual environment at all; just `RUN pip install ...` into the "system" Python.  One approach here could be to just remove the virtual-environment setup entirely.)

Comment: Extract a [mcve] please. Also, read the description of the tags you applied. You can [edit] your question to fix both issues.

Comment: Instead of all the explicit `COPY` commands, you can `COPY ./` and use `.dockerignore` to exclude what you don't want from the project dir in the container.